# How can I multyply spaces and repair my code in haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

Specify the function that appends a text to a given length by appending a sufficient amount of space to the beginning of the text! If the text is not shorter than the required length, it does not need to be modified.
The problem is with the a * " ",it is not working. How can I multiply spaces?

```
format :: (Integral a) => a -> String -> String
format a "b"
  | length "b" <length a = a * " " ++ "b"
  | otherwise = "b"
```

```
Example:
format 5 "" == ""
format 10 "haskell" == "haskell"
format 3 "haskell" == "haskell"
```

Comment: It is a pythonism to try a syntax like `count * " "`. In Haskell, a function returning a list of N identical items would have for its type signature: `:: Int -> a -> [a]`. If you inject that into the [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D&scope=set%3Astackage) specialized search engine, you land immediately on library function [`replicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate). Hence you can try: `replicate count ' '`

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your examples, since it just stays the same in every case.
That being said, a simple solution for the problem using recursion should be something like this:

```
format :: (Integral a) => a -> String -> String
format i str = i>length(str) ? (format (i-1) " "+str) : str
```

Without recursion on the main function you could do this:

```
format :: (Integral a) => a -> String -> String
format i str = i>length(str) ? (concat $ replicate (i-length(str)) " ")++str : str
```

This functions both append spaces to the start of the string!